# How to preserve post entry details after leaving a page (like on StackOverflow)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've noticed that on some sites, StackOverflow included, that if I start writing a post (Title, description etc), then leave the page - I might come back and click on the 'Ask Question' link a day later and the details are prefilled exactly from where I was the day before.

I was wondering how this is best achieved when developing a site using ASP.NET MVC? I was thinking that storing it in Session would expire after x minutes and it'd be too much to try to store in a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

You can save post in database by ajax even if user doesn't push save button, there is many browser events that you can use to save post while user is on page. As example you could start saving post every x seconds after user focuses one of form input fields, or after user enters certain amout of characters, page onunload event would be good place to store post too, but you can't rely on it because browser could be killed and not closed gracefully. So just save post in your database with flag "Unpublished", and load it next time user comes to same page.

Comment: what if user has more than one unpublished post?

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid if we are talking about posts then you just store as many posts as user starts writing but never saves. Store them for example in "Drafts" category, like gmail does. If we are talking about comments, then store as many unpublished comments and store additional info (post id as example) so that you now from where this comment is and when to show it to author. In any case I don't think it is technical problem but domain problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

1. Don't expire the session.
2. give it a "dedicated" session that lives longer than a normal session
3. store it in the browsers local SQL db (this doesn't move with
   the
   user)
4. if it's short enough, store it in   the cookie.
5. associate it with the logged in user, and allow them to store only "one".

Answer (score 0):

Do autosave every short periud of time and save it to cookie/server database.

If you'll save it to cookie then user can continue typing in his browser next time, but he won't be able to continue message on another PC or browser.

Otherwise using database can have rather big load on database and bandwidth if there are many users in your application.